# Importing a classic asp site into TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control

How would i import a legacy website into Team Foundation Server (2015)?

A few websites are classic asp and some other websites are static websites and documents.

Within the collection admin there is an option to add files... but these are just listed in the code window with the existing folder structure no longer maintained....

I want to import an exact copy of the existing folder structure for each website.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the import window shows a list of files, they will be imported with structure in tact.